# Use files as input to Jenkins JobDSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to use Jenkins' JobDSL plugin to programatically create jobs. However, I want to be able to define the parameters in a file. According to docs on distributed builds, this may not be possible. Anyone have any idea how I can achieve this? I could use the readFileFromWorkspace method but I still need to iterate over all files provided and run JobDSL x times. JobDSL code below. The important part I am struggling with is the first 15 lines or so.

```
#!groovy

import groovy.io.FileType

def list = []

hudson.FilePath workspace = hudson.model.Executor.currentExecutor().getCurrentWorkspace()

def dir = new File(workspace.getRemote() + "/pipeline/applications")
dir.eachFile (FileType.FILES) { file ->
  list << file
}

list.each {
    println (it.path)
    def properties = new Properties()
    this.getClass().getResource( it.path ).withInputStream {
        properties.load(it)
    }

    def _git_key_id = 'jenkins'

    consumablesRoot = '//pipeline_test'
    application_folder = "${consumablesRoot}/" + properties._application_name

    // Create the branch_indexer
    def jobName = "${application_folder}/branch_indexer"


    folder(consumablesRoot) {
        description("Ensure consumables folder is in place")
    }

    folder(application_folder) {
        description("Ensure app folder in consumables spaces is in place.")
    }

    job(jobName) {

        println("in the branch_indexer: ${GIT_BRANCH}")

        label('master')

      /*  environmentVariables(
                __pipeline_code_repo:  properties."__pipeline_code_repo",
                __pipeline_code_branch:  properties."__pipeline_code_branch",
                __pipeline_scripts_code_repo:  properties."__pipeline_scripts_code_repo",
                __pipeline_scripts_code_branch:  properties."__pipeline_scripts_code_branch",
                __gcp_template_code_repo:  properties."__gcp_template_code_repo",
                __gcp_template_code_branch:  properties."__gcp_template_code_branch",
                _git_key_id: _git_key_id,
                _application_id:  properties."_application_id",
                _application_name:  properties."_application_name",
                _business_mnemonic:  properties."_business_mnemonic",
                _control_repo:  properties."_control_repo",
                _project_name:  properties."_project_name"
        )*/

        scm {
            git {
                remote {
                    url(control_repo)
                    name('control_repo')
                    credentials(_git_key_id)
                }

                remote {
                url(pipeline_code_repo)
                name('pipeline_pipelines')
                credentials(_git_key_id)
                }
            }
        }

        triggers {
            scm('@daily')
        }

        steps {

            //ensure that the latest code from the pipeline source code repo has been pulled
            shell("git ls-remote --heads control_repo | cut -d'/' -f3 | sort > .branches")
            shell("git checkout -f pipeline_pipelines/" + properties."pipeline_code_branch")


            //get the last branch from the control_repo repo
            shell("""
    git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/remotes | grep -i control_repo | head -n 1 > .last_branch
    """)

            dsl(['pipeline/branch_indexer.groovy'])
        }


    }

    // Start the branch_indexer
    queue(jobName)
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with using `readFile` and `sh` to list the files and then read them? I think you could make this way less complicated.

Comment: Can you run sh outside of job scope?

Comment: Ok, I think I may have been slightly misunderstanding your question before. It looks like you have a "regular"/freestyle/some other job that runs the Job DSL and it wants to use some local files from the workspace for the Job DSL. Is that correct? Are the local files coming from an SCM? If they are, I think this could be greatly simplified by using the Pipeline job type and running the `jobDsl` step in there. You won't have to deal with Jenkins internal classes as much and will use established patterns for pipelines. That is just my opinion, though.

Comment: Didn't want to do that because of the rework involved. I figured it out anyways.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, sorry for my unhelpful comments!

Comment: No worries. I appreciate the assistance, and I understand what you were going for and I agree. Use pipeline where possible, since it's native while JobDSL is not. But with some context, I wasn't able to re-write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to get it working with this piece of code:

```
hudson.FilePath workspace = hudson.model.Executor.currentExecutor().getCurrentWorkspace()
// Build a list of all config files ending in .properties
def cwd = hudson.model.Executor.currentExecutor().getCurrentWorkspace().absolutize()
def configFiles = new FilePath(cwd, 'pipeline/applications').list('*.properties')

configFiles.each { file ->

    def properties = new Properties()
    def content = readFileFromWorkspace(file.getRemote())
    properties.load(new StringReader(content))
```

Answer (score 4):

In case someone else ends up here in search of a simple method for reading only one parameter file, use `readFileFromWorkspace` (as mentioned by @CodyK):

```
def file = readFileFromWorkspace(relative_path_to_file)
```

If the file contains a parameter called `your_param`, you can read it using `ConfigSlurper`:

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(file)
def your_param = config.getProperty("your_param")
```