# Jenkins Job DSL - can't load parmeters from file

Tags: jenkins, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

DSL job:

```
#!groovy

def file = readFileFromWorkspace('params.properties').trim()


job('app-adm') {
  label("adm")
  println("#" + file + "#")
  parameters{
    file 
  }
  steps 
  {
    shell(readFileFromWorkspace('script-adm.sh'))
  }
}

job('app-tst-mt')
{
  parameters 
  {
     booleanParam('FLAG', true)
  }
  steps 
  {
    shell(readFileFromWorkspace('script-tst-mt.sh'))
  }
}
```

params.properties:

```
choiceParam('OPTION', ['option 1 (default)', 'option 2', 'option 3'])
```

I've tried:

- [Use files as input to Jenkins JobDSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49633520/use-files-as-input-to-jenkins-jobdsl)
- adding through single variable like `x=<param> and parameteres { x }`
- different formats

Nothing is working, through println inside job, I can clearly see that there is string that I want to put in parameters, but when doing so it dosen't register it and I don't get any params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, the answer is stupidly obvious but if anybody has same problem just make a shell job previous to DSL job in Jenkins build.
In this shell job you can easily modify files in workspace, so place there a whole dsl job (groovy script), and just replace parts of text with sed or envsubst.